# Screen Locked causing Unable to find explicit activity class have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: java, android, activitynotfoundexception

I have been getting this error in my application for quite a sometime now at few client devices. I have posted a related question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44276566/exception-android-content-activitynotfoundexception-unable-to-find-explicit-act?noredirect=1#comment75562253_44276566) but found not useful answer.

After weeks of research and testing, i reproduce this error at development machine.

On `login` activity, after user insert required credentials and click `Login button`, I am running a `AsyncTask` to validate the credentials over the server. In between i am showing `ProgressDialog` to the user. In case if am **locked the device** during `doInBackground` execution using device hardware lock key or it dims by own and lock, `PostExecute` method throws exception. Following is code snippet of `PostExecute`. Normally without **Locking** the device it works well

```
if(EveryThing Goes Well) 
{                     
    progressDialogUtil.Dismiss();
    Intent selectBikeActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SelectBike.class);
    startActivity(selectBikeActivity); // Here Raised Exception
    finish();
}
......
```

StackTrace is

```
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.yego.motodriver/com.yego.motodriver.SelectBike}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3968)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3920)
                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4259)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4227)
                                                 at com.yego.motodriver.Login.HandleLoginResponse(Login.java:502)
                                                 at com.yego.motodriver.Login.access$300(Login.java:61)
                                                 at com.yego.motodriver.Login$4.onGRPCTaskCompleted(Login.java:233)
                                                 at com.yego.util.GrpcTask.onPostExecute(GrpcTask.java:297)
                                                 at com.yego.util.GrpcTask.onPostExecute(GrpcTask.java:38)
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5742)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

How to avoid this Exception ?

Comment: your package is mismatch for com.yego.motodriver.SelectBike . just control and click over this class .if it will redirect to your original package then it is correct .otherwise you have to change the package.

Comment: @Radhey In my case, If device is locked in between async task, then only exception throws. Otherwise it works well. So i think PackageMismatch will not be the issue here..

Comment: post your Asynctask code .

Comment: Are you calling any library activity from your main project?

Answer (score 0):

> You have not declare your activity in AndroidManifest.xml like :

```
<activity
        android:name=".SelectBike"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Comment: Please read the Question and issue reproduce case before answering

Comment: I have already posted link where i had paste my manifest file sample. Please look at it

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225067/unable-to-find-explicit-activity-class-have-you-declared-this-activity-in-yo?rq=1